# Check for errors in consecutive number filenames

Tags: batch-file, cmd, filenames

I am in desperate need of some kind of tool that lets me check and list which files are missing in a batch of consecutively numbered filenames.
My files are named:

FP_0000001.tif, FP_0000002.tif, FP_0000003.tif, and so on, up to FP_0006543.tif, for example.

The thing is, that when I check the number of files in the folder, it will tell me there are only, let's say, 6500 files, so I know there are 43 missing files, but I don't know exactly which ones.

Searching online, I found this thread that has a similar question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236164/how-to-find-missing-files-with-sequential-names

However, this is for Linux. Is running something like this possible using Windows?

Thanks in advance for your help! Hope I made myself clear. English is not my mother tongue

Answer (score 1):

Instead of porting the bash (Linux) solution to cmd (Windows), you can install bash on Windows and run the original script, please see   https://superuser.com/questions/608106/how-can-i-use-a-bash-like-shell-on-windows

A third option, on Windows 10 Anniversary Update, is to enable the Linux subsystem and run bash natively.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done so that it can run on Linux, Mac, and Windows using PowerShell. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell is available. Linux and Mac and Windows can install from https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

=== Find-MissingFiles.ps1

```
$BaseDir = 'C:/src/t/fp'
$FilenameFormat = 'FP_{0:0000000}.tif'

$UsedList = @()
Get-ChildItem -File -Path $BaseDir -Filter 'FP_*.tif' |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Name -match '^FP_(\d*)\.tif$') {
            $UsedList += [int]$Matches[1]
        }
    }

for ($i = 1; $i -lt $UsedList.Count; $i++) {
    if ($UsedList[$i] -ne ($UsedList[$i - 1] + 1)) {
        $MissingList = @(($UsedList[$i-1] + 1)..($UsedList[$i] - 1))
        foreach ($item in $MissingList) {
            "Missing $($FilenameFormat -f $item)"
        }
    }
}
```

If it must be run from a .bat script file, this can be used.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File '.\Find-MissingFiles.ps1'
```

If you get to PowerShell Core 6 or 7, use:

```
pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -File '.\Find-MissingFiles.ps1'
```

Answer (score 1):

This Batch file do what you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "i=10000000"
for /F %%f in ('dir /O:N /B FP_*.tif') do (
   set /A i+=1
   if /I "%%f" neq "FP_!i:~1!.tif" call :ShowMissingFiles "%%f"
)
goto :EOF


:ShowMissingFiles file
if /I "%~1" equ "FP_%i:~1%.tif" exit /B
echo "FP_%i:~1%.tif" missing
set /A i+=1
goto :ShowMissingFiles
```